# How To Include CSS Before App Load in Angular + Webpack + Heroku Application

Tags: css, angular, heroku, webpack, assets

I currently have an Angular (v4.0.1) application using webpack and deployed to Heroku. I have a loading spinner set up to display on the page while the app is loading. Currently I have it set up so that it works locally, but for some reason when I deploy to heroku the loading spinner (or rather more specifically the CSS to spin the loading spinner) doesn't appear to be pulled in.

I've tried a number of possible fixes but I'm having a hard time figuring out what I need to change to get this to work in production and everything I've found on stackoverflow seems to only work locally. I should also clarify that all of my css files within the app (as in the component styles that load once the app has loaded) work fine, its just the one css file that I have included in the index.html specifically for the loading spinner that needs to be available before the Angular app loads.

My file structure (simplified):

```
.
+-- config/
+-- src/
|   +-- app/
|   +-- assets/
|      +-- icons/
|          +-- loading-spinner.svg
|      +-- stylesheets/
|          +--- loading-spinner.css
|    +-- vendor/
|    +-- index.html
|    +-- main.ts
|    +-- polyfills.ts
|    +-- tsconfig.json
+-- package.json
+-- server.js
```

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Stylist Suite 2.0</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/assets/stylesheets/loading-spinner.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <ss-app>
      <div class="loading-spinner ss-loading"></div>
    </ss-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

The loading-spinner.css file:

```
/* --- Loading Spinner - Needed Before App Loads ---*/

.loading-spinner {
  width: 42px;
  height: 44px;

  background: url("../icons/loading-spinner.svg") no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation: spin 2.5s linear infinite;

  -webkit-animation: spin 2.5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.loading-spinner .ss-loading {
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-21px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

My webpack.common.js (located under config/)

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },

  devtool: 'source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ loader: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
      },
      {
         test: /\.css$/,
         include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
         loader: 'raw-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'assets'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ loader: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'assets'),
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [
          {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: { configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json') }
          }, 'angular2-template-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
          helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

My webpack.dev.js (located under config/)

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.API_APPLICATION_ID': JSON.stringify(""),
      'process.env.REDIRECT_URL': JSON.stringify("http://localhost:4200/login"),
      'process.env.API_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify("http://localhost:3000"),
      'process.env.SITE_URL': JSON.stringify("http://localhost:3000")
    })
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
});
```

My webpack.prod.js (located under config/)

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.API_APPLICATION_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_APPLICATION_ID),
      'process.env.REDIRECT_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.REDIRECT_URL),
      'process.env.API_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_BASE_URL),
      'process.env.SITE_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.REDIRECT_URL)
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      htmlLoader: {
        minimize: false // workaround for ng2
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

Again, all of my assets (other stylesheets, images under the icons folder) load fine, once the app has loaded, because they are being handled properly by the various css and file loaders in my webpack.common.js. I am assuming the issue has to do with my webpack.prod.js file because all of this works perfectly locally but everything I try seems to not fix the issue at all, the loading-spinner.css file is not being loaded at all. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi thanks @peeskillet I updated it so it now includes my webpack.common.js, webpack.dev.js, and webpack.prod.js .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your configuration it looks like you just followed the [Angular docs on webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) verbatim. In those docs, they make use of a global stylesheet `src/assets/css/styles.css`. They imported this in the `AppComponent`

```
import '../assets/css/styles.css';

@Component({
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

What this will do is cause the [`ExtractTextPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/) to extract the text from the (in this case css) file that you `import` or `require`, put it in a `styles.css` file, and add that file as a `<link>`. The output file name has no correlation to the actual filename. `styles.css` just happens to be the name configured for the `ExtractTextPlugin`.

If you check the `dist` folder, and check out the `index.html`, you will see that this `styles.[hash].css` file is added as a `<link>`.

That being said, you should do the same with the loader css. Just import it into the `AppComponent`. This will cause the loader css *content* into the `styles.[hash].css`. If you want to have the loader css separate from the other global styles, think again, as it doesn't really matter. The browser doesn't start rendering until all the style sheets are loaded anyway.

The reason it works for the dev server, is because the dev sever works a little differently. It's configured to add a public path for the server to it can server up files from a location.

In this case, the assets are accessible from the server. But when you build for production, these assets are not transferred. They need to be imported somewhere, as this is how webpack works for the most port. With the import, webpack knows that it's a module that should be build for distribution.

You also don't need to add the loader css to the `index.html` manually, as you have done. It will work both for dev and production, just by importing it. Also you don't need to import the svg anywhere, as webpack will already detect it in the loader css url, and transfer it in the production build

Comment: Yep, when I first set it up I tested with a styles.css included in the app component by above but whenever I tried to start the server I got the following error: 

`ERROR in ./src/assets/stylesheets/loading-spinner.css
Module build failed: Unknown word (1:1) > 1 | module.exports =` followed by the styles.css file. 

The same thing is happening now with the loading-spinner.css which is why I was looking for an external way to include the css file. Is there another way to include it outside of app.component.ts?

Comment: Also, there wasn't enough room in my comment above @peeskillet but I really appreciate your explanation of how the dev and prod servers are working here. Our app has been using systemjs since June and we're just switching over to webpack now so it's a little new for me.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure about that error. I just tested. I have a project that is pretty much a verbatim of the docs I referred to, and just added a random css loader file. And it worked.

Comment: Have you googled for any related issues? like https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/295 or https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/352 or https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/362. There are a bunch more with the search "Module build failed: Unknown word (1:1) > 1 | module.exports"

Comment: I just went back and noticed I had two extra css loaders dealing specifically with the assets folders. I had added them a day before while trying to debug an unrelated sass loading issue, well before I tried to add in our loading spinner and because at the time there was no css in the file I didn't realize they were a problem or at all connected to this issue until now. That must have been what was causing the error with importing the styles.css file, and now the loading-spinner.css file. I just removed it and it seems to be fixed now. Thank you *so* much for your help!

Comment: Oh yeah @peeskillet I had googled at the time but none of the issues with that error fixed my issue, probably because no one submitting those issues had thought to add two unnecessary additional css loaders as part of debugging a sass issue (my bad). But fortunately its fixed now and thank you again for helping me out.